# Regex Bash to match a condition

Tags: python, regex, shell, if-statement

I wish to match below patterns and then proceed for a shell script in Jenkins. The strings should always start with CMR- and SP- and should be followed up with 4 numbers like below. I am having problem in matching this case for a digit of 4 numbers in the range from 0-9. Any language will do.

So my purpose is this. I want to run a script based on below conditions. If the environment doesn't match xyz which is production and doesn't match tickets id's for example CMR-1234 or SP-1234 then script should exit and not run my deployment script.

Can someone please help me out?

CMR-1256 and SP-1278

My bash expression is like below.

```basg
end () {

exit 1

}

echo $CMR


if [ ! `echo $CMR | grep -cE "^CMR-{0,9}|^SP-{0,9}" ` -gt 0 -a $environment == "xyz" ]

then

echo "None of the conditions met"
   end 

  fi
```

I just modified my question to give it more clarity.

Comment: Four digit pattern is `[0-9]{4}` (ERE and NFAs) or `[0-9]\{4\}` (BRE). I have no idea what you are going to use. Treat it as a hint.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However, its not working as supposed. I have used below grep condition grep -cE "^CMR-[0-9]{4}|^SP-[0-9]{4}" but my script is proceeding even with CMR-123455. I want it to limit to just CMR-5432 (4 characters). I tried the other comment too.

Comment: Is it the precedence of the `!` that is the issue?  Can you clarify the purpose of the `-a $environment == "xyz"`?  The `!` at the front will alter that to `!=`.  By the way, your RE in your comment is *different* to the one shown in your question.  AND, do you want *exactly* 4 digits or *up to* 4 digits?

Comment: So my purpose is this. I want to run a script based on below conditions. If the environment doesn't match xyz which is production and doesn't match tickets id's for example CMR-1234  or  SP-1234 then script should exit and not run my deployment script.

Comment: @cdarke my requirement is exactly 4 digits after CMR- or SP- and that should always be a number.

Comment: As an aside, `grep` knows how to set its exit code so `if` can see if it matched a regex. `if [ $(grep -c foo) -eq 0 ]` is better written simply `if grep -q foo`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it is using `bash` RE rather than `grep`:

```
#!/bin/bash

end () { exit 1; }

environment="xyz"

for CMR in CMR-1256 gash SP-1278
do
    echo $CMR

    if [[ ! $CMR =~ ^(CMR|SP)-[0-9]{4}$ ]] || [[ $environment != "xyz" ]]
    then
        echo "None of the conditions met in $CMR $environment"
        #end
    else
        echo "$CMR matched $environment"
    fi
done
```

Gives:

```
CMR-1256
CMR-1256 matched xyz
gash
None of the conditions met in gash xyz
SP-1278
SP-1278 matched xyz
```

Comment: Sorry but this is also not working. When I am passing 5 numbers along with SP OR CMR, its still working .                                                       
 end () { exit 1; }



    echo $CMR

    if [[ ! $CMR =~ ^(CMR|SP)-[0-9]{4} ]] || [[ $deployment_environment != "production" ]]
    then
        echo "None of the conditions met in $CMR $environment"
        end
    else
        echo "$CMR matched $environment"
    fi

Comment: OK, I'll fix that.  `$` added at the end of the RE.